How well does the English chess rating system predict results of games between under 18s and established adult players?
The English rating system makes it possible for someone to get a full rating without every playing a person with a full rating or playing anyone who have played someone with a full rating. Hence a large group of children could all be rated without any of them having played a rated game against a rated adult.
How bad is this, or is it just a theoretical issue?
See https://www.ecfrating.org.uk/v2/help/help_rating.php
